# jquery click event tr or input clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").live('click',function(){
       alert("TR");
    });

    $("input").live('click',function(){
        alert("INPUT");    
    });    
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fj93z/)

How can I just trigger the click function for the checkbox without triggering the tr function? Is there any solution with jQuery?

I will not set return false at the end of the input function and I really need the tr element too.

**Info:** [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) doesn't work on live() events.

Comment: A fiddle is a great thing to add to a question, but please also post the code in to the question too. That way people can help you should jsFiddle be offline, and this question will also be useful in the future.

Comment: I'm using live(), instead of click()

Comment: Could you post your code using `live()`. As an aside, don't use live - it's slow and has been deprecated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought live() is the only function to work with manipulated DOM Data? Isn't it?

Comment: better to use `delegate()`, or if you're using jQ1.7+ `on()`. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: I'm changing a complete table after an ajax call. With live() i can handle the new elements but with delegate nothing happened. :-/

Comment: now i changed live to delegate and event.stopPropagation still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method on the event object.

It will prevent the event from bubbling up without cancelling the default event behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").click(function(){
       alert("TR");
    }); 

    $("input").click(function(e){
        alert("INPUT");    
        e.stopPropagation();
    });    
});
```

---

As it seems you are using .live() and not direct event binding, you can't use stopPropagation().

First of all, `.live()` is **legagcy code and has been deprecated**, which means it could be removed from the library in any future new version. I don't know which version of jQuery you are using but you should consider moving to the latest (which is more optimized anyway) and use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event delegation.

Nevertheless, if you can't upgrade your jquery library, here's maybe a solution to your problem. The event parameter passed to all event handler contains a property `target` which reference the element from which the event was initiated. So you could do something like:

```
$("tr").live('click',function(e){
    if (e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
    // if ($(e.target).is('input') === false) { // jquery style but maybe less efficient
       alert("TR");
    }
});
```

Not very elegant but does the trick. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/gcfQT/).

The problem with `.live()` is that events are binded to the document so as more complex as your application would become, you may end up with headaches to stop propagation.

In the meantime I've made a fiddle using `.on()` ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/kJxau/)) and one using `.delegate()` ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/VceJe/)).

Comment: is e.stopPropagation(); working between two different files? my two functions are in different js files and i think this is the reason why it doesnÄt work.

Comment: ok, it doesn't work because i'm using live() instead of click().

Comment: Having the code in different files does not matter. What version of jquery are you using ? .live() has been deprecated and you should not use it anymore. See [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `stopPropagation()` to your `input` click handler. It will stop the event bubbling up the DOM to parent elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").click(function(){
       alert("TR");
    });

    $("input").click(function(e){
        alert("INPUT");    
        e.stopPropagation();
    });    
});
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/LwvYD/1/)**

**OP Updated Question:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("TABLE").delegate("tr", 'click',function() {
       alert("TR");
    });

    $("TABLE").delegate("input", 'click',function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("INPUT");    
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stopPropagation()` for input handler

http://jsfiddle.net/KJg6Q/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LwvYD/2/

`e.stopPropagation()` in handle on input or use `e.relatedTarget`

```
$("tr").click(function(e){
       if( e.relatedTarget.tagName != "input" )
           alert("TR");
    });
```